# How can I build multi head CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a multi-head CNN for classification.
I want 2 binary classifications at the last layer.
1st classifier is Triangle vs. Rectangle.
2nd classifier is Center vs. not in Center.
Also, I have a separate dataset for each classifier, and I want to train one classifier at a time.

but when I test or predict suppose I want all classifiers to work.
for example 1:
I passed one image which had a triangle in the center.

Classifier 1:
Triangle[0]
Rectangle[1]

Classifier 2:
Center[0]
Non-center[1]

Then the output must be [0,0] # because the image has a triangle that's why the first 0 in the vector and then the triangle is in the center of the image then again 0 in vector.

Example 2:
I passed one image which has a square in it but not in the center, then my output must be [0.5,1], where 0.5 represents that it does not belong to classifier 1 and in classifier 2 it belongs to 1(not in the center).

How can i do this ?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

# Multi-head CNN for bongard problems
input_shape = (100, 100, 1)
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)

shared_layer = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
shared_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(shared_layer)
shared_layer = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(shared_layer)
shared_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(shared_layer)
shared_layer = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(shared_layer)
shared_layer = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(shared_layer)
shared_layer = Flatten()(shared_layer)

# Classifier 1: Triangle vs Rectangle
classifier1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(shared_layer)
output1 = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier1')(classifier1)

# Classifier 2: Center vs Not-Incenter
classifier2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(shared_layer)
output2 = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='classifier2')(classifier2)

# Create the multi-head model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output1, output2])
```